# Trigger change on all selects but the triggered one

Tags: jquery

So I have some select elements and when a change event is triggered on one of them, I want to trigger that on the others as well. I am getting "Call stack size exceeded" when using the code below:

```
$('select').change(function(e){
    $('select').not(this).change();
});
```

I think that the error is given because there is an infinite loop in some way here, but I can't see how that could be.

Comment: and `$('select').not($(this)).change();` ?

Comment: I tried that as well with the same result

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering other `select` change event which then will trigger in their turn all other ones, and so on.... Resulting in infinite loop.

Your <strike>best bet</strike> is to check if event is triggered manually, not by user interaction:

```
$('select').change(function(e) {
  if (e.isTrigger) return;
  $('select').not(this).change();
});
```

**EDIT**  Ok my bad, your best bet is to check for `event.originalEvent` instead:

```
$('select').change(function(e) {
  if (!e.originalEvent) return;
  $('select').not(this).change();
});
```

[See why](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/319)

From main dev core:

> not sure it's ready to be part of the public API

Answer (score 0):

This happens because on other selects you have the same event. Let's assume you have 2 selects: 1 and 2.

When 1 is changed then change event occurs and triggers the change event on 2 (that's what you want). But the change event on 2 also triggers change events on all other selects (that is already the thing you want to avoid). And here you have an infinite loop, which is by the way even not linear.

What you probably can do is setting some flag in a global variable (or another way like adding some property to the `event.data` object, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) which will be activated only for the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid inifite loops is:

```js
$('select').change(function (e, data) {
  if (data) {
    return;
  }
  $('select').not(this).trigger('change', [{FromMyself: "ok"}]);
});
```